# Un-stacking textures that are stacked over each other

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have an UDIM texture.

When I load my model in ZBrush, the UVs are stacked on top of each other, and that makes painting it really difficult:

[image]

I would therefore like to "un-stack" it in Blender.

It should look like this:
[image]

Could anybody please tell me how to do?

I have uploaded the Blend file here: (contains nudity)
 http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47958

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still want to do this after reading pie75's answer, the [MultiEdit Addon](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?339369-MultiEdit-ALPHA-2%2528Major-Update%2529-Multiple-Objects-Editing)   might come in handy.

1. Select all objects, go to MultiEditMode.
2. Then select a face, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> -> `Image`
3. Move the UVs in UV Editor by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>256</kbd> (in this case, other value might be needed for other cases).
4. Hide the faces with <kbd>H</kbd> and proceed with another yet unhidden face, but this time move for the double amount.
5. When all UVs are moved, exit MultiEditMode and you are done.

*Blenderman* example (without hiding faces):
[image]

Comment: I installed MultiEdit and I tried to do as suggest but something always goes wrong. Would you be willing to show it to me for two face so that I can see the workflow?

Comment: See my edit. Hiding faces is not necessary but is helpful so that one doesn't forget any textures.

Answer (score 3):

UV Maps automatically wrap, in all my experiences. Vertex points with a value greater than 1 wrap back to past 0, and lower than 0 wraps back to past 1.

The solution, then, is to make sure all your UV vertices stay within the bounds of the UV map(which is 0-1). Scale your UV's down, and move them into positions within the UV space.

Other than that, you could use multiple materials, or multiple UV maps. Add a new material from the material tab in your object, or add a new UV map slot under the mesh tab.

Comment: Thank you. Did you take a look at my Blend file? I'm not sure, but I think the model already has multiple materials.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not, sorry. It was 2AM and I was about to collapse. In fact, I did collapse 20-30 minutes later.
Your model does have multiple Materials, but since all the objects are separated, and each of their materials have an index of 1, I feel that may cause a bunch of problems when importing them as a single thing.
Then again, I don't use ZBrush..